# Problem with sharepoint search

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have created the Contact list. I feed proper data where required in my personal sharepoint site. Bu when I look for the specific name or any key word that present in contact list it shows message :

No results matching your search were found.

1. Check your spelling. Are the words in your query spelled correctly?
2. Try using synonyms. Maybe what you're looking for uses slightly different words.
3. Make your search more general. Try more general terms in place of specific ones.
4. Try your search in a different scope. Different scopes can have different results.

Where is, I am giving proper inputs by following these instructions. What should be problem. Is i nees to make any setting for make my data searchable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must config your search engine at SharePoint Central Administration. Or ask your administrator to config this.